# Custom DatabaseException doesn't work in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My aim is to output a standart **"Service not available"** message for whole database error messages. (Version: Laravel 10)

So I created DatabaseException.php under Exceptions:

```
class DatabaseException extends ExceptionHandler
{
    ...
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\QueryException) {
            return response()->view('pages.servicenotavailable');
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

In Handler.php, I added following to include this exception to the system:

```
protected $dontReport = [
    \App\Exceptions\DatabaseException::class,
];
```

But I still see database error, not my custom view.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean you want to set different messages to different errors? Service not available for database errors and different messages for different errors ?

Comment: I want to output servicenotavailable view for all database errors. Not 404, 500; database related errors.

Comment: Another question , did you try disabling the debugging by setting APP_DEBUG=false?

Comment: Yes, also tried changing APP_ENV, didn't make any difference.

Comment: I think you have to register the exception in the register part of Handler.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I directly coded exception handling within Handle.php

```
public function handleException($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\QueryException) {
        // Customize the error page for database exceptions
        return response()->view('pages.servicenotavailable', [], 500);
    }
}

// And than I registered:
public function register(): void
{
    $this->renderable(function(Exception $e, $request) 
    {
        return $this->handleException($request, $e);
    });    
}
```